# Return Column Name in User Defined function instead of Value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I have a table which has more than 40 columns all stored in varchar. The some of the columns contain data which is numeric or date too.

I have a user defined function which takes the column name and datatype as arguments, and tries to validate the data in the column.

If the validation fails, it should return a message saying 'ColumnName is not numeric or is missing'. However it returns 'Value is not numeric or is missing'.

The code of function is:

```
create function [dbo].[fn_Polaris_Validate_Staging_Data](@ColumnName varchar(max), @TargetValidation varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
Declare @Remark varchar(max);
    if(@TargetValidation = 'Standard' and @ColumnName is null)
    BEGIN
        select @Remark = @ColumnName + ' is not provided.'
        return @Remark
    END
    if(@TargetValidation = 'NumericType' and ISNUMERIC(@ColumnName) = 0)
    BEGIN
        select @Remark = @ColumnName + ' is not numeric or not provided.'
        return @Remark
    END
    if(@TargetValidation = 'DateType' and ISDATE(@ColumnName) = 0)
    BEGIN
        select @Remark = @ColumnName + ' is not proper date or not provided.'
        return @Remark
    END
    return isnull(@Remark, '')
END
```

I have a column called 'remarks' in my table which saves this remark. This is the way I use this function in my update query:

```
UPDATE TABLE TABLE1
SET remarks = isnull(remarks,'') +
              function(Interest, 'NumericType') +
              function(Asset, 'Standard') +
              function(Date, 'DateType')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ISNUMERIC(@variable)` will only work on the string contents of that @variable, it won't refer to any column name within the string.

```
declare @col as varchar(max)
set @col = '1'
select ISNUMERIC(@col)
= 1

declare @col as varchar(max)
set @col = 'table.id'
select ISNUMERIC(@col)
= 0 - regardless of the type of table.id
```

Maybe this will be of use?

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE Table_Name='mytable' and Column_Name='mycolname'
```

Comment: I meant to say that all the data is actually stored in varchar (max) but the data of columns is like '123.23' (numeric data stored in varchar) and '02/18/2013' (date data stored in varchar).

Comment: Unless you strictly enforce it somehow, a given column could contain either numeric or text... there's no way for SQL to tell unless you examine a specific row. You could SELECT TOP 1 (MS SQL) to get the first row, and examine what's in that...? Maybe you'd be better off having table and column definitions stored somewhere...

Comment: I'm loading all the data from a CSV file using SSIS and saving everything as varchar initially. After that I cleanse the data in SQL.